# Monotone convergence theorem - why this is important? $0 \leq f_k(x) \leq f_{k+1}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

$0 \leq f_k(x) \leq f_{k+1}(x)$ is a condition in the Monotone convergence theorem, but why is that? wouldn't it work just the same for $ f_k(x) \geq f_{k+1}(x) \geq 0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, this only works if at least one of the $f_k$ is integrable.

For example, the sequence $f_k(x) = I\{x \ge k\}$ is non-increasing and converges pointwise to $f(x) = 0$. But 
$$\infty = \int_0^\infty f_k(x) \, dx \not\to \int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx = 0.$$

Of course if $0 \ge f_k(x) \ge f_{k + 1}(x)$ holds for all $k$, then you can interchange the limit and the integral. This is just an application of the monotone convergence theorem to the sequence $-f_k$.